# c# Where is source view in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I recently installed VS 2015 for a study course. In a Windows Form Applications project, my label is hidden when the text property is set to empty and there appears to be no way to reset the text value once it is hidden, except by code behind. This seems rather extreme just to make this label visible again. Does VS 2015 have a source view window?

Answer (score 1):

In Solution Explorer (View -> Solution Explorer) you can open Form1.cs -> Form1.Designer.cs -> Form1 and see and edit the initialization of the form, also you can see Form1() constructor of the your form where will be event handlers.

Comment: Ok, but none of these windows can render my label visible again. While hidden, I cannot add values to any properties except by code behind.

Comment: @matt2605 can you please share the source code in the Form1.cs -> Form1.Designer.cs -> Form1

Comment: No I cannot. This is my assignment. The point is, with the text property empty, the label is hidden in design view and I cannot do anything with the label except from code behind. I haven't changed any other properties.

Comment: @matt2605 have you looked for event handlers in Form1() constructor?

Comment: @matt2605 there in Form1.cs -> Form1.Designer.cs must be something like this Form1.cs -> Form1.Designer.cs -> Form1 https://monosnap.com/file/68j4ZOSmlWruY1TWtTYePC3GHEooGH

Comment: There's only InitializeComponent() in it. I have have to recreate the project everytime I make a mistake like this. Just seems inadequate.

Comment: @matt2605 if there is nothing associated to your label then it seems that you have just deleted it from designer.

Comment: Nope, like I said. I can set values to the label such as text from the Form1.cs. I am getting a warning about this extended discussion and we don't seem to be heading in the right direction. Maybe we should stop here.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the source view by pressing F7 from the design view.

If not, you can go to View->Other Windows->Document Outline (Ctrl+Alt+T) from your Designer. There you can see the control and set the properties from there.

Comment: It is not what I expected. I expected to see my controls in code form and not the methods in code behind. So that while the controls are hidden in design view, I could still change any control property in another window. I want to add a text value to make it visible again actually. Does this not exists?